# add office tools to Microsoft team s

Tags: microsoft-teams

i have an issue related to Microsoft team development app. 
my  target is to creating app collect all office tools (word, onenote, excel and powerpoint ) as a multiple tabs in one app and pin the app to all users 
i use app studio to create tab , personal tab and add excel or word web link as "https://www.office.com/launch/excel?auth=2" .. app is created but tab is blank and white empty screen. 
any advice related to this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty tab because it's trying to load `https://login.microsoftonline.com` in iFrame for authentication. Currently, only SharePoint site can be added as private tab by adding webApplicationInfo to support SSO. 
https://www.office.com/ is currently not supported.

Please make your features suggestions on the [Microsoft Teams feedback portal on UserVoice](https://aka.ms/microsoftteamsplatformsuggestions).